# Hebrew, Arabic, Yiddish text is written in reverse order in PDFBox 2.0.5

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to write some Arabic, Hebrew and Yiddish characters in PDF but they are written in reverse order. I am using PDFBox 2.0.5 to create and write in PDF document.

My sample code

```
String relativeWebPath = "/font/arial.ttf";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);

ByteArrayOutputStream output=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDDocument document=new PDDocument();
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File(absoluteDiskPath));
PDPage test=new PDPage();
document.addPage(test);
PDPageContentStream content=new PDPageContentStream(document, test);
final String EXAMPLE = "النص العربي";
System.out.print(EXAMPLE);

 content.beginText();
 content.newLineAtOffset(50, 680);
 content.setFont(font, 12);
 content.showText(EXAMPLE);
 System.out.print(EXAMPLE);
 content.endText();

 content.close();

 document.save(output);
 document.close();
```

While researching for solution I found that it is handled by adding ICU4j library in project but it not works for me and also icu4j dependency is removed from PDFBox 2.0 ([PDFBox-2118](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2118)).

Comment: RTL language and complex scripts are not supported in PDF creation, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to handle it at our end as this is not handled by PDFBox itself. Ok I have some workaround for this, create reverse string of RTL language characters and pass it to PDFBox then PDFBox will write it in the correct direction.

Now the next question is how to detect the text of RTL language and how to reverse it then the solution is here, this can be achieved by using java's BiDi class object.

Complete solution, this solution handles mix of strings also :

```
    String word = EXAMPLE; // string from question
    Bidi bidi = new Bidi(word, -2);
    if (!bidi.isMixed() && bidi.getBaseLevel() == 0) {
        return word;
    }
    else {
        int runCount = bidi.getRunCount();
        byte[] levels = new byte[runCount];
        Integer[] runs = new Integer[runCount];

        for (int result = 0; result < runCount; ++result) {
            levels[result] = (byte) bidi.getRunLevel(result);
            runs[result] = Integer.valueOf(result);
        }

        Bidi.reorderVisually(levels, 0, runs, 0, runCount);
        StringBuilder bidiText = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < runCount; ++i) {
            int index = runs[i].intValue();
            int start = bidi.getRunStart(index);
            int end = bidi.getRunLimit(index);
            byte level = levels[index];
            if ((level & 1) != 0) {
                while (true) {
                    --end;
                    if (end < start) {
                        break;
                    }

                    char character = word.charAt(end);
                    if (Character.isMirrored(word.codePointAt(end))) {
                        bidiText.append(character);
                    }
                    else {
                        bidiText.append(character);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                bidiText.append(word, start, end);
            }
        }

        return bidiText.toString();
    }
```

This solves my issue. Hope it will help others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot! Do you know how to apply your solution to multiple lines? I manually process every line separately but it looks like Bidi has a createLineBidi method that may be easier to use. Any idea?